# Why an exception is raised when I insert a token as a value of an html src attribute

Tags: forms

How to raise the exception:

In any text_area field using ckeditor, insert the following code `<img src="[node:my_custom_token]">` and save the form.

You will get the following error: (assuming the edited form was `http://mysite/fr/node/8/edit`)

```
page not found|127.0.0.1|http://mysite/fr/node/8/[node:my_custom_token]
```

This is a `NotFoundHttpException` thrown in `RouterListener`

Here is the trace

```
PHP internal call Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\RouterListener->onKernelRequest(Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Event\GetResponseEvent $event)
<ROOT>/core/lib/Drupal/Component/EventDispatcher/ContainerAwareEventDispatcher.php:142 call_user_func($function_name, $parameters)
<ROOT>/vendor/symfony/http-kernel/HttpKernel.php:134 Drupal\Component\EventDispatcher\ContainerAwareEventDispatcher->dispatch($event)
<ROOT>/vendor/symfony/http-kernel/HttpKernel.php:80 Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\HttpKernel->handleRaw(Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request $request, int $type = 1)
<ROOT>/core/lib/Drupal/Core/StackMiddleware/Session.php:57 Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\HttpKernel->handle(Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request $request, $type = 1, $catch = true)
<ROOT>/core/lib/Drupal/Core/StackMiddleware/KernelPreHandle.php:47 Drupal\Core\StackMiddleware\Session->handle(Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request $request, $type = 1, $catch = true)
<ROOT>/core/modules/page_cache/src/StackMiddleware/PageCache.php:106 Drupal\Core\StackMiddleware\KernelPreHandle->handle(Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request $request, $type = 1, $catch = true)
<ROOT>/core/modules/page_cache/src/StackMiddleware/PageCache.php:85 Drupal\page_cache\StackMiddleware\PageCache->pass(Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request $request, $type = 1, $catch = true)
<ROOT>/core/lib/Drupal/Core/StackMiddleware/ReverseProxyMiddleware.php:47 Drupal\page_cache\StackMiddleware\PageCache->handle(Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request $request, $type = 1, $catch = true)
<ROOT>/core/lib/Drupal/Core/StackMiddleware/NegotiationMiddleware.php:52 Drupal\Core\StackMiddleware\ReverseProxyMiddleware->handle(Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request $request, $type = 1, $catch = true)
<ROOT>/vendor/stack/builder/src/Stack/StackedHttpKernel.php:23 Drupal\Core\StackMiddleware\NegotiationMiddleware->handle(Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request $request, $type = 1, $catch = true)
<ROOT>/core/lib/Drupal/Core/DrupalKernel.php:716 Stack\StackedHttpKernel->handle(Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request $request, $type = 1, $catch = true)
```

Comment: Do you mind to explain the down votes. I think it is valuable for anyone to understand the process behind the "validation" (by ckeditor?) of the url in the html attributes like src.

Comment: Your token isn't getting replaced. I can't tell you why not though. Maybe the text filter you are using doesn't replace tokens. It won't have anything to do with your editor though.

Comment: Thank you @Jaypan. My question is not about the replacement of the token but I would like to understand which/where is the process/code which is validating the url of an image src attribute. This is not a token related question: the exception is raised if you replace the token by a string like "i_am_not_a_token"

Comment: The token is not being replaced when the template/page is rendered, so the browser is requesting a URL that does not exist. That is basically it. Either the filter is not processing tokens, or there is something wrong in your custom token logic.

Comment: Kevin filled in the reason why the answer I gave is resulting in the error you are seeing.

Answer (score 3):

If you are editing an entity and you save the entity, you are redirected to the page showing the entity.
As in the entity content you added `<img src="[node:my_custom_token]">`, the browser is trying to access http://your-site-domain/[node:my_custom_token] to get the image data for the image it should show. Drupal doesn't find any route associated with that URL and it logs a *Page not found* error and throws an exception.

That isn't related to using tokens, as that could happen whether you enter a URL for your site that doesn't exist, for the *src* attribute.

If you are wondering why that token isn't replaced, that's because the entity form field isn't set to replace tokens, which it can also happens when the entity field is a *Text (formatted, long)* field for which none of the input filters set for its format handle tokens.

Comment: Thank you!! What is strange, is the fact that the site is not redirecting to the page showing the (custom) entity; thus I don't know where the rendering happens... Anyway, regarding "Drupal doesn't find any route associated with that URL and it logs a Page not found error and throws an exception." Is it possible to avoid it? [FYI: This is a config entity which is storing templates (html + tokens) to produce pdf in other part of the site]

Comment: The question says the form was on http://mysite/fr/node/8/edit. That's a node entity, not a configuration entity.

Comment: You are right, it was to not over complicate the question... a very bad idea!!! The real path is `admin/structure/token_templates/pdf_aw_card_body/edit` where `pdf_aw_card_body` is the id of my config entity (Before asking the question here, I tested with a regular edit node route and the exception was also raised...)